# converted if else to switch statements

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement, switch-statement, photo

This is the code that I've created so far and it's not working. I'm just a beginner and we are creating this "guess your zodiac" code as one of our school works.

Please help me change what's wrong with the code :((

Also (sorry if im asking for too many things) how can I insert a photo in every case, such that as there is a photo for every zodiac sign?

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1> Guess your ZODIAC </h1>
  <script>


window.confirm("HELLO");
window.confirm("I will try to determine your ZODIAC SIGN via this html. Cooperate with me :) ?");
window.confirm("oki, lego");

var zodiacmonth = prompt("Please insert your birthMONTH; if your birthday is on January 11, insert January");
var zodiacday = prompt("Please insert birthDAY; if your birthday is on January 11, insert 11")

switch (sign) {
   case ((zodiacmonth == "February" && zodiacday >= 19) || (zodiacmonth == "March" && zodiacday <=20)): 
   window.confirm ("Your zodiac sign is PISCES");
   break;

   case ((zodiacmonth == "March" && zodiacday >= 21) || (zodiacmonth == "April" && zodiacday <=19)):
   window.confirm ("Your zodiac sign is ARIES");
   break;

   case ((zodiacmonth == "April" && zodiacday >= 20) || (zodiacmonth == "May" && zodiacday <=20)):
      window.confirm ("Your zodiac sign is TAURUS");
      break;

   case zodiacmonth == "May" && zodiacday >= 21 || zodiacmonth == "June" && zodiacday <=20 : 
      window.confirm ("Your zodiac sign is GEMINI");
      break;

   case zodiacmonth == "June" && zodiacday >= 21 || zodiacmonth == "July" && zodiacday <=22:
      window.confirm ("Your zodiac sign is CANCER");
      break;

   case zodiacmonth == "July" && zodiacday >= 23 || zodiacmonth == "August" && zodiacday <=22 :
      window.confirm ("Your zodiac sign is LEO");
      break;

   case zodiacmonth == "August" && zodiacday >= 23 || zodiacmonth == "September" && zodiacday <=22: 
      window.confirm ("Your zodiac sign is VIRGO");
      break;

   case zodiacmonth == "September" && zodiacday >= 23 || zodiacmonth == "October" && zodiacday <=22: 
      window.confirm ("Your zodiac sign is LIBRA");
      break;

   case zodiacmonth == "October" && zodiacday >= 23 || zodiacmonth == "November" && zodiacday <=21:  
      window.confirm ("Your zodiac sign is SCORPIO");
      break;

   case zodiacmonth == "November" && zodiacday >= 22 || zodiacmonth == "December" && zodiacday <=21:  
      window.confirm ("Your zodiac sign is SAGITTARIUS");

   case  zodiacmonth == "December" && zodiacday >= 22 || zodiacmonth == "January" && zodiacday <=19: 
      window.confirm ("Your zodiac sign is CAPRICORN");
      break;

  case  zodiacmonth == "January" && zodiacday >= 20 || zodiacmonth == "February" && zodiacday <=18: 
        window.confirm ("Your zodiac sign is AQUARIUS, like mine :))");
      break;



   } 

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't do comparisons with `switch...case` statements. You have to keep using `if`s

Comment: try `switch (true) {` instead - as `sign` is not declared anywhere, what do **you** think it is?

Comment: I would recommend you keep using `()` all the way down too in the case statements, not sure why you stop after taurus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `case` isn't the same as a `if(/else)` statement.

`switch/case` blocks can be used to check for different values of a **single** variable.

Your conditions include multiple variables, so a `switch/case` block isn't even possible (/practical) here.

That said, this code *can* be optimized, if you structure your data better:

```js
var zodiacs = [
  { sign: "PISCES", monthA: "February", monthB: "March", dayA: 19, dayB: 20 },
  { sign: "ARIES", monthA: "March", monthB: "April", dayA: 21, dayB: 19 },
  { sign: "TAURUS", monthA: "April", monthB: "May", dayA: 20, dayB: 20 },
  // etc
];

var zodiacmonth = prompt("Please insert your birthMONTH; if your birthday is on January 11, insert January");
var zodiacday = prompt("Please insert birthDAY; if your birthday is on January 11, insert 11")

var zodiac = zodiacs.filter(function(z){
  return zodiacmonth == z.monthA && zodiacday >= z.dayA ||
    zodiacmonth == z.monthB && zodiacday <= z.dayB;
})[0]

console.log(zodiac);

window.confirm ("Your zodiac sign is " + zodiac.sign);
```

It may also be useful to make the month comparison case insensitive:

```
zodiacmonth = zodiacmonth.toLowercase();
// and
{ sign: "PISCES", monthA: "february", monthB: "march", dayA: 19, dayB: 20 },   
//                         ^                   ^
```